# Multiple Level Nested Layout in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

I have an application with a global application layout file `application.html.haml`. I then have multiple "controller stacks": for our main site, our admin portal, and our business site. For each of these, controllers are within a module and all inherit from the same `BaseController`. Each stack has it's own layout file. Within the stack, some controllers have layout files as well.

I would like all views (unless otherwise specified) to render inside multiple levels of nested layouts : application, "stack", "controller".

For example, for the `Site::BlogController#show` action, I'd like rails to render:

`/site/blog/show.html.haml` inside `/layouts/site/blog.html.haml` inside `/layouts/site.html.haml` inside `/layouts/application.html.haml`

I am having difficulty understanding how to insert `/layouts/site.html.haml` into the stack. It appears as though automatically, rails will render the action inside the controller layout inside the application layout, however, I can't see how to "insert" layouts into the render stack.

Any help is greatly appreciated, however, I have read all the rails guides to no avail, so a link to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts will not really be helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I reread the link i posted ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts ) and realized I missed a key detail.

```
<%= render :file => 'layouts/application' %>
```

so, in `Site::BaseController` I have a call to `layout 'site'` and in `/layouts/site.html.haml` I have

```
= content_for :footer do
   -#Content for footer
= render :file => 'layouts/application'
```

Then in `Site::BlogController` which extends `Site::BaseController` I have `layout 'site/blog'` and in `/layouts/site/blog.html.haml` I have

```
=content_for :header do
  %h1 HELLO WORLD!

= render :file => 'layouts/site'
```

This then renders the layouts nested as described in the question. Sorry for missing this in my question. I should've read closer.

Answer (score 9):

if you create a helper like this:

```
# renders a given haml block inside a layout
def inside_layout(layout = 'application', &block)
  render :inline => capture_haml(&block), :layout => "layouts/#{layout}"
end
```

then you can define sublayout like this:

```
= inside_layout do
  # nested layout html here
  = yield
```

these layouts can be used like normal layouts.

more: http://www.requests.ch/blog/2013/10/30/combine-restful-rails-with-nested-layouts/

Comment: Thanks for this, this was exactly what we were looking for! We also found out that you can do this with just using `capture(&block)`, and this answer will work with ERB as well, because [HAML aliases `capture_haml` to `capture`](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/4.0.5/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb#L56)

Answer (score 3):

I've done similar, but only used 1 level of sublayouts. Can easily be tweaked to allow multiple levels.

In controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
def sub_layout
  nil
end
```

In controller (for example blog_controller.rb):

```
def sub_layout
  "blog"
end
```

In layouts/application.html.erb rather than `<%=yield%>`:

```
<%= controller.sub_layout ? (render :partial => "/layouts/#{controller.sub_layout}") : yield %>
```

Make a partial `layouts/_blog.html.erb`:

```
...code
  <%=yield%>
...code
```

Repeat for other controller & sub layouts.

EDIT:
If you need to do this on a per-action basis:

```
def sub_layout
  {
    'index' => 'blog',
    'new' => 'other_sub_layout',
    'edit' => 'asdf'
  }[action_name]
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is much harder to generalize to larger nesting structures and requires a decent about of custom code. I was trying to avoid a solution like this.

Comment: Also using this method, but I find the 3 lines it takes up if you need it on a per action base frustrating, any ideaS?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the simplest way to do it is by adding this line of code in the parent of a nested layout:

```
((render "layouts/#{controller_name}" rescue nil)|| yield )
```

you could add as many nested layouts as you want by only changing the path directory of the next layout to be rendered.

**note**: make sure your nested layout is named  _layoutname.whatever and that your nested layout has a **yield** inside

Comment: `rescue nil` here is _very very_ bad: any error happening in the rendering of that file and you'll be oblivious.  None of your users might be able to access the main page of your site and you wound't have idea.  Just stop using `rescue nil`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial with a yield in it.

_my_sub_layout.html.erb:

```
<h3>I'm a sub layout and here's my content:</h3>
<%= yield %>
```

In some other view or even in your main layout application.html.erb render the partial as a layout:

```
<%= render layout: 'my_sub_layout' do %>
  <p>I'm the sub layout's content</p>
<% end %>
```